# MySQL: How to Get a Value from a Table That has Duplicate Entries of that Value?

Tags: mysql

I have a SourceTable like:

```
ColumnA   ColumnB   ColumnC   ...
1         a         apple
2         b         ball
3         c         car
4         a         apple
5         p         pizza
```

`ColumnB` and `ColumnC` has duplicate values.

My code is:

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable
SELECT 'Bob', ColumnB, ColumnC, now(), ... FROM SourceTable
WHERE ColumnB = 'a';
```

I just need to enter a single value in `TargetTable`. The result should look something like:

```
Bob   a   apple   currentTime   ...
```

The problem am having is each duplicate entry is being entered in `TargetTable`.

EDIT: btw, `a` in `WHERE ColumnB = 'a';` is dynamic. It changes based on a user interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Theory-based answer, with no knowledge about the use cases that drove the DB design

This scenario is often avoided by breaking Columns B and C off into a parent table with a unique key on Columns B and C. Then, use a foreign key column in SourceTable to reference the parent table.

As for your INSERT statement, Column B and C will be references to the parent table, where it's guaranteed that you'll have a unique Column B and C value, thereby avoiding the duplicate entry error.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization with regard to reducing data redundancy, for example the duplicate Column B and C (a, apple) values in SourceTable.

### But if DB redesign isn't an option for one reason or another...

You can use SELECT DISTINCT

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable
SELECT 'Bob', ColumnB, ColumnC, now(), ... FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnB, 
ColumnC from SourceTable) derived_table
WHERE ColumnB = 'a';
```

Comment: Sorry for the amature question, but how does the derived_table look like?

Comment: No need to apologize for genuine questions. derived_table is an alias for the table resulting from the subquery (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnB, ColumnC from SourceTable).

Comment: Do I need to create the derived_table? What other code is associated with derived_table?

Comment: You don't need to create derived_table separately from the INSERT statement, and you never "see" it during the statement. If you want to see what the table looks like for debugging purposes, try to run the select distinct... query standalone. For reference on MySQL derived tables: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html

Comment: I had another issue inside my query preventing yours from executing successfully.. It works! I Appreciated your help!